# In a BoundColumn in a DataGrid, how do I format a byte[] column as a string?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm passing a datebase reader object to a `DataGrid` and it sees one of my columns as type `byte[]` but I happen to known that it should always be a printable string. How can I force the .NET DateBinding system to do that conversion? The only place I can see to put anything is in `BoundColumn.DataFormatString` but I can't find any indication how to do what I need with that.

---

*Edit:* I known how to convert a `byte[]` to a `string` in general but don't know how make the `BoundColumn` do it.

Because in this case I can edit the query string, I hacked passed it by using `PADR(column,0) as column` in the `SELECT`. I'm still interested in what to do if I couldn't modify the query.

Comment: What is the content of that byte array? A name? An image? An actual GUID type code? That might effect how the translation from byte[] to string is made.

Comment: It's the result of calling .stacktrace on an Exception and bouncing it though an SQLite BLOB column.

Comment: Hmm, could you update your question a little more to outline your process. I'm confused as to if you want the handling method to do the conversin, the database reader to do the conversion, or if you want the data converted out of the SQLite database into a string before all the process starts off.

Comment: The place I'd expect it to get converted is in the BoundColumn object as some format directive or some kind of callback: here's the object, please return a string to be used.

Comment: There are no built-in format strings for array types, so you're out of luck. However, you can do almost anything if you switch to a TemplateColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) to get the string (make sure you use the correct encoding where UTF8 is present - there is ASCII, UTF7, UTF8, Unicode, and UTF32).